# Blank File generating, while Converting EPMA generated “.ADS” files for their Planning, HFM, HPCM and Essbase outlines to a DRM import format

Tags: java, oracle, ads, arabic, hyperion

Blank File generating, while Converting EPMA generated “.ADS” files for their Planning, HFM, HPCM and Essbase outlines to a DRM import format. And .ads file contain some Arabic word's

```
To run the converter, follow the ReadMe document and the step-by-step actions also captured.
Step -1: Navigate to the <Patch_Extract>\src folder in Command Prompt
Step -2: Set the JRE path variable
Step -3: Run the Java Compiler by executing the below command for the Main class –
Javac ADS_DRM.java
Step -4: Execute the Java Program using the below command:
Java ADS_DRM<Space>“ADS File name”<Space>”Target.txt”
```

File getting generated with 0 Byte/Blank file

Please suggest how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several way to convert `.ads` files for their Planning, HFM, HPCM and Essbase outlines to a DRM import format

A) **By changing system/Server setting as give below** `(Require Administrative Privilege's on System/Server)`

1. Control Panel
2. Clock and Region
3. Region

and in Region Tab Select **Administrative**

**->** **Change system Locale** and select **Region specific language** for example i have selected `Saudi Arabia`

[image: How to change system setting]

And then use below steps

```
Step -1: Navigate to the <Patch_Extract>\src folder in Command Prompt
Step -2: Set the JRE path variable
Step -3: Run the Java Compiler by executing the below command for the Main class –
Javac ADS_DRM.java
Step -4: Execute the Java Program using the below command:
Java ADS_DRM<Space>“ADS File name”<Space>”Target.txt”
```